# How to use fragment inside fragment activity

Tags: android

i am a newbie in android development. I have created a fragment Activity and a Fragment(by the name of MainFragment) and when i add an instance of the MainFragment class to the activity it starts showing the error on the highlighted lines in the below add. Can anyone help please. Thanks !

MainActivity.java

package com.vitarkasolutions.fb_smsandcallreader;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private MainFragment mainFragment;
    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            mainFragment = new MainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            **.add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)**
            .commit();
        } else {

            **mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);**
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: looks like its a case of wrong import. check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

to

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Since you extend `FragmentActivity` make sure your imports for `MainFragment` is from the support library.

You are adding Fragment to the container which is a ViewGroup such as a FrameLayout.

```
add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
```

`android.R.id.content` is the id of the container.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html#content

Id used from the android framework

```
public static final int content

Added in API level 1
Constant Value: 16908290 (0x01020002)
```

You don't need this

```
 mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
```

Generally you will have a `ViewGroup` in our xml to which you add/repalce fragments

Example :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container" // i defined own id
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity"
    />
```

Then

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private MainFragment mainFragment;
private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(container, mainFragment) // use the id of the container
        .commit();
    } 
}
```